Is there a way to make Mathematica return only the solution to an integral that is real?
I am looking to find a consistent way of finding integrals that result in inverse trig functions. I have been able to convert the output of
Integrate[D[ArcSin[2 x/3], x], x]

being
I Log[-2 I x + Sqrt[9 - 4 x^2]]

into an ArcTan form, which I then convert to an ArcSin form, though this form still differs to the original ArcSin[2x/3], being a translated Pi/2 units positively in the vertical axis and it does not work on a more general scale. An ideal solution to my issue would output ArcSin[2x/3] in this case and would work on a more general scale eg. D[ArcSin[2x+1/3], giving only real solutions to integrals.

I get ArcTan[(2 x)/Sqrt[9 - 4 x^2]], which is equivalent (no translation) to ArcSin[2x/3]. (V14.1)

It appears that the next release will give the desired result. `In[2]:= Integrate[D[ArcSin[2 x/3], x], x] // InputForm
Out[2]//InputForm= ArcSin[(2*x)/3]I don't know if that was intentional or lucky, but withIntegrate` I'm inclined to expect it's the latter.


use assumptions to specify that variables are real and constrained (some experimentation needed)
use definite integration because what you ask for is not possible in general for indefinite integrals

Integrate[D[ArcSin[2 x/3], x], {x, 0, y}, Assumptions -> -3/2 < y < 3/2]

(*    ArcSin[2 y/3]     if y >= 0    *)



An ideal solution to my issue would output ArcSin[2x/3]

<< Rubi`
Int[D[ArcSin[2 x/3], x], x]


To install Rubi, this is the command
PacletInstall["https://rulebasedintegration.org/Rubi-4.16.1.0.paclet"]


As I mentioned, I already get a real result:
overlaid[n_] := Reverse@Table[AbsoluteThickness[1.5 k], {k, n}]; (*plotstyle*)
$Version
primitive = ArcSin[2 x/3];
assum = FunctionDomain[D[primitive, x], x]
antideriv = Integrate[D[primitive, x], x] (* could use Assumptions here *)
Plot[{antideriv, primitive}
 , {x, MinValue[{x, assum}, x], MaxValue[{x, assum}, x]}
 , PlotStyle -> overlaid[2]]


Here's a way to obtain a real result from the OP's reported output with a generically equal derivative:
Assuming[assum,
 I Log[-2 I x + Sqrt[9 - 4 x^2]] // Re // ComplexExpand // 
   ReplaceAll[a_Arg :> ArcSin@Sin@a] // FullSimplify
 ]
(*  ArcSin[(2 x)/3]  *)

We took the real part and converted Arg[] to the desired trig form. Of course, if there are mixed trig functions, such as primitive = ArcSin[2 x/3] - ArcCos[2 x/3], it may be impossible to split up Arg[] to get primitive; probably theoretically impossible, as it is with inverting Integrate[D[Sin[x]^2, x], x], Integrate[D[-Cos[x]^2, x], x], and Integrate[D[Sin[2x], x], x].

Use Rubi. It makes integration so much easier (I'm still new to it but it seems very impressive).
Int[D[ArcSin[2 x/3], x], x]
outputs:
(ArcSin[(2 x)/3])
Look into Rubi if you are having trouble getting nicer-form integrals.
